# How to Add a badge to my ImageView in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, badge

I am recently working on a chat app. I have a trouble here about handling the incoming messages.

I have a tableview which shows all the dialog that i have. Once i receive the new messages i want to add some numbers (which is similar to the badges on the app) on the icon of that cell. I try to  add a subview to the cell at the upper-left of the corner? I am not quite sure about this.What can i do to implement this?

[The table view cell's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXfag.jpg)

Comment: Adding an Image View and Label on top of it is the right approach. So are you facing any problem?

Comment: i mean does it have to be so complicated? i don't know if there is  a simpler approach?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any other method. 
There is built-in support for adding badge over Tab Bar Controller's tab or App Icon, but not image view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use https://github.com/Marxon13/M13BadgeView pod library. Simply add badge view to a cell image like in sample bellow:

```
M13BadgeView *badgeView = [[M13BadgeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24.0, 24.0)];
badgeView.text = @"1";
[cell.imageView addSubview:badgeView];
```