# Show only first frame of a GIF IOS SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I've been using SDWebImage With swift and my app loads dribble shots, but sometimes when its a GIF it leaks the memory.. can I please know how can I display a GIF but only its first frame showing and a small GIF logo which shows the user its a GIF. So I can prevent memory leaks.
Please mind, I am only 12 and fairly new to iOS Development.

Thanks in Advance
Aryan

Comment: try this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857716/how-to-add-a-badge-to-my-imageview-in-ios/28858223

Comment: these libs..should also help..https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif &/or https://github.com/kaishin/Gifu